# Remove column headers from python (bokeh) in html

Tags: python, html, excel, pandas, bokeh

I want to display this format in HTML view using python codes (bokeh)

[image: I want to display this format in HTML view using python codes (bokeh)]

[I have done the same with the other table but have used the column headers. But in this case, I don't have column headers. You can find the codes of the above image as:

```html
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="Campaign", title="Campaign"),
        TableColumn(field="#Leads", title="Leads"),
        TableColumn(field="Touched Lead", title="Touched Leads"),
        TableColumn(field="Actual Touched Rate", title="Actual Touched Rate"),
        TableColumn(field="Month since campaign launch", title="Month since campaign launch"),
        TableColumn(field="Expected Touched Rate", title="Expected Touched Rate"),
        TableColumn(field="%Achieved Touched Rate (Actual/Expected)", title="%Achieved Touched Rate (Actual/Expected)"),
        TableColumn(field="Signings", title="Signings"),
        TableColumn(field="NRR (Touched)", title="NRR (Touched)")
    ]

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, fit_columns=True,selectable = True,sortable = True, width=1200, height=300)
```

What changes should I make in the above codes so that Headers are not displayed in html?

[image: What changes should I make in the above codes so that Headers are not displayed in html?]